# Client domains on Plesk not using SSL when accessing admin on 8443

Tags: ssl, server, admin, plesk

I have spent 2 days trying various solutions breaking the stack multiple times... you are my only hope:)

I have setup Plesk on an aws instance and i'm using a webhost license.

Set up a hostname, issued a certificate with lets-encrypt, and works fine when accessing the admin interface on `hostname.com:8443`

Set up a client domain, issued certificate with let-encrypt, works fine for the front end but when i want to enter admin on `clientdomain.com:8443` i get a privacy error. Same thing when trying to access admin with the server ip only as well. In both cases it tries to pull the certificate of "hostname" instead of the cert issued to the client domain.

The goal is to get clients `clientdomain.com:8443` and server ip working with ssl or to redirect to `hostname.com:8443`

I would like to understand what's happening and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles across the same issue:

Currently this is not possible in Plesk (Obsidian18.0.27) but its being considered

As a temporary solution the best practice is to redirect all `clientdomain:8443`
requests to `hostname:8443` and force https to ensure secure connection.

To achieve this follow these instructions:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001421414